# Jquery load HTML data in real time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am calling the getContent method recursively and plotting the values in real time in the HTMLtable. But  after the recursive ajax call the new results are getting appended to the existing table rather than updating the table. how do i clear the table data every time before I re populate the table?

HTML:

```
        <table id="personDataTable" class="table table-bordered">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>workflow_job_id</th>
                <th>Domain Id</th>
                <th>Entity Id</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Task Status</th>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
```

Script:

```
function getContent(){
//ajax call to retrieve the data from DB.
drawTable(dat);
}

function drawTable(data) {

        setTimeout(getContent, 60000);
        for (var i = 0; i < data.resultSet.length; i++) {
            drawRow(data.resultSet[i]);
        }
    }

    function drawRow(rowData) {
        var row = $("<tr />")

        $("#personDataTable").append(row); //this will append tr element to table... keep its reference for a while since we will add cels into it
        row.append($("<td>" + rowData.workflow_job_id + "</td>"));
        row.append($("<td>" + rowData.domain_id + "</td>"));
        row.append($("<td>" + rowData.entity_id + "</td>"));
        row.append($("<td>" + rowData.type + "</td>"));
        row.append($("<td>" + rowData.status + "</td>"));
        row.append($("<td>" + rowData.taskstatus + "</td>"));
    }
```

Comment: Why are you surprised that the content is being appended when you use the .append() method?

Comment: Stop appending rows to the table?

Comment: Yes i am aware of the the append() but looking for an alternative for the same. something like  $("#personDataTable").empty() before i append the rows to the existing table.

Comment: So... use `empty`? You also have your headers in the `<tbody>` which doesn't seem quite right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you remove row before appending, like this:

```
function getContent(){
//ajax call to retrieve the data from DB.
drawTable(dat);
}

function drawTable(data) {

    setTimeout(getContent, 60000);
    $("#personDataTable").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.resultSet.length; i++) {
        drawRow(data.resultSet[i]);
    }
}

function drawRow(rowData) {
    var row = $("<tr />")

    $("#personDataTable").append(row); //this will append tr element to table... keep its reference for a while since we will add cels into it
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.workflow_job_id + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.domain_id + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.entity_id + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.type + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.status + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.taskstatus + "</td>"));
}
```

Comment: Nope. Its still the same.

Comment: @user3746601 It works fine for me .

See the  [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vikashvverma/2k7xupnz/)

Comment: You have only one entry in the data array. But i have multiple entries. If you have multiple rows of data it fails to work.

Comment: @user3746601 I have updated the code above. Hope this works. 

Remove rows except header before adding : `$("#personDataTable").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();`

Comment: I got it. It seem to work now. I ll update the code. Please mark this as a correct answer. Thanks Vikash!

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
function drawRow(rowData) {
    var row = $("<tr />")

    $("#personDataTable").append(row); //this will append tr element to table... keep its reference for a while since we will add cels into it
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.workflow_job_id + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.domain_id + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.entity_id + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.type + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.status + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.taskstatus + "</td>"));
}
```

to

```
function drawRow(rowData) {
    var row = $("<tr />")

    $("#personDataTable").find('tr').remove();
    $("#personDataTable").append(row); //this will append tr element to table... keep its reference for a while since we will add cels into it
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.workflow_job_id + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.domain_id + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.entity_id + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.type + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.status + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.taskstatus + "</td>"));
}
```

to remove the old rows before appending

Comment: I tired this but its not working. It removes all the 'tr' except the last one in the data.